# Specify the env file docker compose uses

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to specify the env file that docker compose uses for variable substitution? Currently it defaults to ".env" but I have different flavours of compose files which should have different envs.

Comment: I found this https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/ but this appears to need env_file for each container.. Is it possible to set it globally for the whole docker-compose file thus overriding the default .env?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use inheritance for this. If you have one "base" service where you set up the environment, all of your other services can inherit from that.

Example:

```
version: "2"

services:
  base:
    env_file:
      - my_env.txt

  web:
    extends:
      service: base
    image: foo

  database:
    extends:
      service: base
    image: foo-db
```

The above example has everything in the same file, but you can also split this up into multiple files, where the `base` service would reside in a `base.yaml` file. You just need to add `file: base.yaml` to the `extends` section. Please see [the documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services).

I use this approach for setting the proxy variables for all containers. I have a `proxy.yaml` file that defines a `proxy-app` service that picks up the proxy environment variables from the shell. All of my real services extend the `proxy-app` service and thus inherit the environment settings from that service.

Comment: Attention: Will not work in docker compose v3 and up

Comment: This will not work on Docker Compose v3+ because each service must have a defined image or a build context. Documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766931/service-notebook-has-neither-an-image-nor-a-build-context-specified-at-least-on)

Comment: This does not address the question, which is how to specify a different .env file, but instead provides a workaround, which is not useful for the vast majority of viewers who are looking for a solution to the question as asked for a variety of reasons

Answer (score 12):

The `--env-file` command-line argument and the `env_file` docker-compose.yml variable specify the env file to use for the container, not for the container build. To set a different file (e.g. *alt.env*) for the build itself, use this:

```
env $(cat alt.env) docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the distinction about --env-file only applying to service deploy and not build, mentioned anywhere in the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option
This seems like really odd behavior. But after digging some more, the use of the env-file has been broken on v2 for years now:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8515

Comment: Correct, it is not a documented behavior.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), it's now possible to load an environment file (contrary to a per-service file), docker-compose will then export the env variables defined in this env file prior to starting any service, they can then be used in the docker-compose.yml config file itself:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  
  node:
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "${APP_ENV}"
      NODE_ENV: "${NODE_ENV}"
    ports:
      - "${HOST_EXPOSED_NODEJS_DEBUG_PORT}:9229"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./project
        target: /var/www/project
        read_only: false
```

Since [docker-compose 1.25](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6170) it's also possible to specify a custom .env file with the [--env-file flag](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) (unfortunately it's currently not possible to specify [multiple .env files with the --env-file flag](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7847))

Comment: This is misleading. --env-file is for specifying *environment variables* for the container, *not* for specifying values to substitute in docker-compose.yml.