# Service notebook has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use `jupyter/base-notebook:latest` image. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  notebook:
    image: jupyter/base-notebook:latest
    build:
      args:
        - NB_USER=appuser
        - NB_UID=1001
        - NB_GID=101
    ports:
      - "3010:8888"
    volumes:
      - "./notebooks:/home/appuser/work"
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get this error:
`Service notebook has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.`
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 options: use an existing image **OR** tell the docker-compose to build it. If both are specified, then Compose names the built image with the `jupyter/base-notebook:latest`.

If you want to use the `jupyter/base-notebook:latest` image as is, remove the `build:` section from your compose file and keep the `image:`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  notebook:
    image: jupyter/base-notebook:latest
    ports:
      - "3010:8888"
    volumes:
      - "./notebooks:/home/appuser/work"
```

If you want to build a custom image, give it a name that does not conflict with the official image name(preferably) and provide a build context:

```
services:
  notebook:
    build:
      context: ./<dir-that-contains-the-dockerfile>
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NB_USER=appuser
        - NB_UID=1001
        - NB_GID=101
    image: <repo>/<img-name>:<tag>
```

Comment: Hi @Neo_Anderson, How can I pass `args` when I am using image section? My OS is ubuntu 20.04. I want to set  `NB_UID=1001` to solve permission deny.

Comment: You can't use arguments if you don't build the image: arguments live only during the build of an image and if you use an image that is already built, it does not make sense to use them. Instead, if you want to **start** the container as a different uid:gid than root, you can add `user: "${UID}:${GID}"` under your `notebook:` service

Answer (score 0):

I addressed this error by updating the `docker-compose` command to the newer `docker compose` (without the hyphen) command, making use of [Compose V2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/)